# Interaction between various forces, by which one is to calculate an angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames, free-body-diagram

I am new to Newtonian mechanics, and was wondering about the following question. I basically have the ingredients for the answer, but I cannot seem to find the way to put this together into one coherent answer.

> A box is attached to a pole, which in turn is attached to the ground, as displayed in the picture. We are spinning the box around the pole at a radial velocity of $\omega_0$. A pendulum with length $L$ and mass $M$ is attached to the box. The distance between the point of attachment of the pendulum to the box and the pole is $R$. $R$ is much smaller than $L$.
>
> [image]
>
> The system is located within an electric field $E$, the direction of which is parallel to the pole (as illustrated by the picture). The box carries charge $Q$. As a result, the particle is subjected to an additional force, the size of which is QE and its direction is the direction of the field (as shown in the picture).
>
> Calculate angle $\theta_0$ between the pendulum and the vertical axis in a state of equilibrium.

$y$ component: $$QE + T\cdot \cos \theta_0 - mg=0$$

$$\cos \theta_0 = \frac{mg-QE}{T}$$

$x$ component: $$\sin\theta_0 \cdot T = F_c$$

$$R_{tot} = R + R_2,$$ with $R$ being the horizontal distance between the pendulum and the right-hand wall of the box

$R$ is much smaller than $L$.

so one can neglect $R$ and state that $R_{tot}=R_2$.

$$\sin\theta_0 · T = M\omega^2R_{tot}$$

$$\sin\theta_0 = \frac{M\omega^2R_{tot}}{T}=\frac{R_{tot}}{L}$$

How does one put this together?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the *particle*, not the box, carries charge $Q$.  I also think you mean $R_2$ is the distance between the particle and the box wall, so $R_2=L\sin\theta_0$.

My initial wrong answer:

> Anyway, I think the only thing you are missing is that you can divide
>   $\sin\theta$ by $\cos\theta$ to get $\tan\theta$.  Then $T$ will
>   cancel and you can take the inverse tangent of both sides to solve for
>   $\theta$.

Correct answer: if $R$ is negligible, then the equation for the $x$ components should be $$T\sin\theta = F_c = m\omega^2L\sin\theta.$$  Thus $\theta$ cancels from the $x$ equation and is left only in the $y$ equation.

Comment: thanks for the correction, Richard! However, I was asked to calculate θ. This means that now, by cancelling out $sinθ$ from $x$, I can do so only by using $y$. So I get $θ=arc cos \frac {mg-QE}{T}$. Is that acceptable as a correct answer?

Comment: The final step is to eliminate $T$ (which is not a given quantity) using the expression from the $x$ components of forces.  Then you'll have an expression for $\theta$ in terms of given quantities $m, g, Q, E, L, \omega$.